# Hibernate use column name for property name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to generate JPA's from hibernate during my build process and everything is working fine except for the naming. The default it looks like is hibernate uses the class type for  the property name. Is there a way to make it use the column name in the database as the property name?

for example in my DB i have a column name customer_org_type which references a table called valid_value to make sure the type is valid. When I generate the table it creates a property called:

```
public ValidValue validValue;
```

but I would like it to generate as:

```
public ValidValue customerOrgType;
```

Is there any way to have that?

Comment: Have you tried the [@Column annotation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm) ?

Comment: I dont wan to touch the generated java files as they will be overwritten every time i do a build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

It required an entry in my hibernate.reveng.xml

Since it was a foreign key reference I just had to add the following:

```
<table catalog="my_catalog" name="user_info">
    <foreign-key constraint-name="customer_org_type_id_fk" >
        <many-to-one property="customerOrgType" exclude="false" />
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```